# Terminology for Transgenes

Tags: terminology, transformation

I'm designing an in vivo delivery vector for therapeutic transgenes.
I have two different potential versions of the transgenes. If they were innate, they'd be referred to as "alleles." Does the terminology change if they're transgenes?

Comment: I think that "variant" would be pretty generally understandable. It might help to know what you mean by "versions". E.g. they homologous? How different are they?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would change to a different terminology. I would not apply the word 'allele', which would be confusing/misleading at best. Even if the transgene is an allele taken from an organism, I would only note such in a writing when needed and still refer to the transgenes themselves by something else.